# Cant see my sprite in drop down

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

Hi guys I am trying to view my sprite instead of the actually arrow that drops down.... I can see my sprite on my index.html with certain elements of it and when I set my sprite to the body I an see it as well.

- **Direct link to sprite** http://s9.postimg.org/s75ip0ez3/sprite.png
- **Live Preview:** http://jsfiddle.net/az3tk5yL/

#### CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'corbel', Arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  background: url(../images/paris3.jpg) no-repeat left top;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo figure {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Hero Section */
.hero-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: corbel;
}
textarea {
  resize:none;
}

}
.scl-area{
  text-align:center;
  margin:0px auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;  
}
.scl-area ul{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  display:inline-block;

}
.scl-area li{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  margin:0px 5px;
  margin-top:14px;
  transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;  
}
.scl-area li a{
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  content:"";
  font-size: 20px;
  float:left;
}
.scl-area li:first-child{
  background:none;
  width:auto;
  float:left;
  margin-top:0px;
  height:auto;

}
.scl-area li:nth-child(3){
  background-position:-55px 0px;  
}
.scl-area li:nth-child(3):hover{
  background-position:-55px -38px;
}
.scl-area li:nth-child(4){
  background-position:-98px 0px;  
}
.scl-area li:nth-child(4):hover{
  background-position:-98px -38px;  
}
.scl-area li:nth-child(5){
  background-position:-141px 0px; 
}
.scl-area li:nth-child(5):hover{
  background-position:-141px -38px; 
}
.scl-area li:nth-child(2){
  background-position: 25px 0px;  
}
.scl-area li:nth-child(2):hover{
  background-position: 25px -38px;  
}
.scl-area li.bdr{
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
}
a.btn-main{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #fff; 
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:14px 10px 15px 70px;
  background-color:transparent;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  position:relative;
  font-size:22px;

  transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
}
a.btn-main:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
  background:#000;
  border:1px solid transparent; 
  background:#27579a; 
}
a.btn-main:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 14px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background-position: -2px -75px;
  top: 9px;
}
.form-section{
  margin:0px auto;
  padding:0px;
  margin-top:20px;
}
.form-section form{
  padding:6px 15px;
  margin:0px;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:7px;
  text-align:left;
  overflow:hiddensq  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.form-section form label{
  width:100%;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#2a2728;
  margin-top:12px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  float:left; 
  padding-right: 5px
}
/* Checkbox Stuff */
.form-section form input{
  color:#2a2728;
  min-height:15px;
  border-radius:4px;
  border:1px solid #2a81bb;
  float:left;
  text-indent:6px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;


}

.form-section form .box1 img, .form-section form .box2 img, .form-section form .box3 img {
  height: 25px;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.squaredTwo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
    height: 25px;

}

.form-section .deflt{
  width:40%;
  margin:0px auto;
  float:none; 
}

/* The CSS */
.form-section form select {
    padding:3px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color:#888;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
  color:#2a2728;
  width:100%;
  text-indent:6px;
  min-height:40px;
  border:0px;
  border-radius:4px;
  border:1px solid #2a81bb;
  float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    cursor:pointer;

}


/* Register Button Styling*/
.button{
  display:inline-block;
  background:#428bca;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding: 15px;
  color:#fff;
  position:relative;
  font-size:22px;
  opacity: 0.85;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 125px;
  transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
}
.button:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* The CSS */
.form-section form select {
    padding:3px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color:#888;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
  color:#2a2728;
  width:100%;
  text-indent:6px;
  min-height:40px;
  border:0px;
  border-radius:4px;
  border:1px solid #2a81bb;
  float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
span label:after{
  background: url('images/sprite.png') no-repeat -56px -78px;

}
.form-section form textarea{
  color:#2a2728;
  width:100%;
  min-height:120px;
  border:0px;
  border-radius:4px;
  border:1px solid #2a81bb;
  float:left;
  text-indent:6px;
}

@media (max-width:1200px){
  .form-section .deflt {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media (max-width:991px){
  body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'corbel', Arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  background: url(../images/paris3.jpg) no-repeat left top;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  }
  .form-section .deflt {
    width: 66%;
  }
}
@media (max-width:830px){
  body {
      margin: 0;
  font-family: 'corbel', Arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  background: url(../images/paris3.jpg) no-repeat left top;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  }
}
@media (max-width:767px){
  .form-section .deflt {
    width: 85%;
  }
  body:before, body:after, .bg-3:after{
    background:none;  
  }
  .logo figure{
    margin-top:70px;  
  }


}
@media (max-width: 600px){
  .hero img {
    width: 60%;
  }

 .box2 {
    background-color: orange;
   margin-left: 100px;
margin-bottom: -100px;
  height:120px;
  padding-left: none;
  text-align: center
}

.box3 {
  background-color: blue;
  width:25px;
}

@media (max-width:560px){
  .form-section .deflt {
    width: 97%;
  }
  .form-section form .box1, .form-section form .box2, .form-section form .box3 {
    width: 49%;
  }
  .form-section form .box3{
    margin-top:20px;  
  }
  a.ctnt-btn{
    font-size:16px; 
  }
  .scl-area li:first-child{
    display:block;
    float:none; 
  }
  .scl-area li.bdr {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    width: 31px;
    border-left: 0px solid #fff;
  }
  .scl-area li:nth-child(2) {
    background-position: -12px 0px;
  }
  .scl-area li:nth-child(2):hover {
    background-position: -12px -38px;
  }
}
@media (max-width:535px){
  .logo figure img{
    width:100%; 
  }
  a.btn-main{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px; 
     margin-left: 250px;
  }
  .content-section .hm-sec h3{
    margin-bottom:20px; 
  }
  .logo figure{
    margin-top:60px;  
  }
  /* Register Button Styling*/
.button{
  display:inline-block;
  background:#428bca;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding: 15px;
  color:#fff;
  position:relative;
  font-size:22px;
  opacity: 0.85;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 85px;
  transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:All 0.3336s ease-in-out;
}
.button:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
  opacity: 1;
}
    span label select:after{
  background: url('images/sprite.png') no-repeat -56px -78px;

}

}
@media (max-width:435px){
  .scl-area li:first-child img{
    width:70%;
  }
  a.btn-main{
    font-size:16px; 
  }
  a.btn-main:after{
    top:5px;  
  }
}
@media (max-width:400px){
  .form-section form .box1, .form-section form .box2, .form-section form .box3{
    width:100%; 
  }
  .form-section form .box2 li .squaredTwo {
    /*margin-left: 22px;*/

  }
  .form-section form .box2{
    /*margin-top:15px;*/
  }
}



/* The CSS */
.form-section form select {
    padding:3px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color:#888;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
  color:#2a2728;
  width:100%;
  text-indent:6px;
  min-height:40px;
  border:0px;
  border-radius:4px;
  border:1px solid #2a81bb;
  float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      body span:after{
        background: url('images/sprite.png') no-repeat -56px -78px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span>
      <label style="font-weight:normal">
        <select id="industry" name="industry" class="select">
          <option value="">Choisissez votre secteur...</option>
          <option value = "produits chimiques"> </ option> Produits chimiques 
          <option value = "Construction"> Construction </ option> 
          <option value = "Engineering"> Ingénierie </ option> 
          <option value = "financier"> financier </ option> 
          <option value = "FMCG"> FMCG </ option> 
          <option value = "Food / Drink / tabac"> Food / Drink / Tabac </ option> 
          <option value = "Gouvernement"> Gouvernement </ option> 
          <option value = "Santé"> Santé </ option> 
          <option value = "Hightech"> Hightech </ option> 
          <option value = "assurance"> Assurance </ option> 
          <option value = "IT Hardware & amp; Software">Matériel informatique & amp; Logiciel </ option> 
          <option value = "juridique"> Juridique </ option> 
          <option value = "fabrication"> Fabrication </ option> 
          <option value = "Media"> Médias </ option> 
          <option value = "but non lucratif">à but non lucratif </ option> 
          <option value = "Oil & amp; Gaz"> Oil & amp; Gaz </ option> 
          <option value = "Outsourcing"> Externalisation </ option> 
          <option value = "Partenaires"> Partenaires </ option>
          <option value = "Pharmaceuticals"> Pharmaceuticals </ option> 
          <option value = "détail"> détail </ option> 
          <option value = "Service Management"> Service Management </ option> 
          <option value = "Télécommunications"> Télécommunications </ option> 
          <option value = "Transport / Logistique"> Transport / Logistique </ option> 
          <option value = "Utilitaires"> Utilitaires </ option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You asked a question about CSS and didn't decide to include any _CSS_. Please add the relevant styles and we can be better prepared to help you. Welcome to SO.

Comment: @ryanh We need to see the sprite to check if you are using the right dimensions...

Comment: Here is the direct link for the sprite image  http://s9.postimg.org/s75ip0ez3/sprite.png

Comment: Where do you have `<LI>` tag in your code???

Comment: Your code is not correct in Syntax! Updated the code: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/az3tk5yL/1/

Comment: Thank you but that still doesn't solve the sprite image not showing up

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this

<span>
      <label class="select-label">
                <select name="itemCount" class="select_fd item_count">
                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                            <option value="5">5</option>
                                            <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
                                            <option value="20">20</option>
                                            <option value="30">30</option>
                                            <option value="50">50</option>
                                            <option value="100">100</option>
                                            <option value="150">150</option>
                                            <option value="200">200</option>
                                    </select>
                </label>            </select>
      </label>
    </span>



.select-label select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    border: medium none;
    color: #000;
    float: left;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    min-height: 40px;
    padding: 9px 8px 8px 2px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    width: 100%;
}
.select-label {border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    min-height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin:20px 0;
}
.select-label:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 27px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.select-label:after {
    background:url("http://s9.postimg.org/s75ip0ez3/sprite.png") no-repeat scroll -52px -78px transparent;
    height: 41px;
    content: "";   
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
   right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 32px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/unicodeLucknowM/zjqpn471/